# addValueEventListener runs even when I just return to the app from a sleep mode

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android app using Firebase Realtime Database.

My `addValueEventListener` for a specific reference runs whenever there is a data change in the database. It also runs whenever the app starts. These make sense to me, but this even runs when I return to my app from a different activity. For example, it runs when I go to the HOME screen of my phone and go back to this app, the `addValueEventListener` runs.

This is a problem for me because I am implementing a `vibration` whenever there is a data change in my app. I put a global `int` variable to prevent `vibration` on the first time i get to the app.

It works like:

```
matchReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(notificationCounter > 0) notifyGoals(getView());

                clearCurrentList();
                notificationCounter++;

                // Fires every single time the channelReference updates in the
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I initialize `int notificationCounter = 0` outside of this function so that it gets reset to 0 whenever I re-run this app. But, whenever I go to a different activity on my phone (HOME Screen or LOCK screen) and return to this screen, it runs the `addValueEventListener` before the `int notificationCounter = 0` initialization. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: create function and call it in addValueEventListener and in that function initialize notificationCounter = 0

Comment: Where do u call matchReference.addValueEventListener? Is it in onResume

Comment: @RissmonSuresh sorry for not mentioning. It's on onStart

Comment: @WaleedAsim what makes that different from what I did in my code?

Comment: @Dawn17 what in this function clearCurrentList(); ?

Comment: Try move it in onCreate

Comment: @RissmonSuresh That does the trick! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `onDataChange()` method is called asynchronous which means that this method does not wait to get the data from your database and is called even before. To solve this, you have 2 choices. One would be to move the declaration of your `notificationCounter` int inside the `onDataChange()` method or second, to dive into the asynchronous word and use my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152775/how-to-get-value-async-in-outside-method-ondatachange).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your valueListener in activity pause

```
private HashMap<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
private ValueEventListener valueEventListener;


 mChatReference.child(groupID).addValueEventListener(valueEventListener=new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    hashMap.put(mChatReference.child(groupID), valueEventListener); 
    removeValueEventListener(hashMap);
    finish();
}
public void removeValueEventListener(HashMap<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> hashMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = entry.getKey();
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = entry.getValue();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }
}
```